# find nodes by attribute and modify at once

Tags: 7, nodes

If I want to filter content by attributes (besides content type name), is there is some module around? if I am able to find these nodes, some way to update this attribute for all nodes at once?

Comment: What do you mean by attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

1. You can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) in combination with [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
2. You can also have a look at [Editable Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) in combination with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

Comment: yeahhh this video http://vimeo.com/26884701 shows exactly how to use VBO, Rules and views for my purposes

Comment: great, glad that this module can help you.